# webdriver.io getting started - Error while creating session with the driver service

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio

I tried default install configs via `npx wdio config` with as service `selenium-standalone` and after that didn't work, `chromedriver` as service. These are the commands I'm running.

```
npm init -y
npm install @wdio/cli -y
npx wdio config
npx wdio run wdio.conf.js
```

The console log error output.

```
Failed to connect to selenium. Attempts left: 25
 connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
2021-12-01T09:07:24.127Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2021-12-01T09:07:24.129Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2021-12-01T09:07:24.703Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - D:\_code\Node\webdriverio\test\specs\example.e2e.js
[0-0] 2021-12-01T09:07:25.248Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2021-12-01T09:07:25.253Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2021-12-01T09:07:25.253Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2021-12-01T09:07:27.287Z WARN webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping drive
r service: Driver server process died prematurely.
```

I expected it to just run out of the box but all I get are these service/driver errors.

I'm on Windows 10, OpenJDK 17.0.1 is installed, it's on `path` and `JAVA_HOME` is set.

I can see the webdrivers in `<project>\node_modules\selenium-standalone`.

I disabled firewall and antivirus but those are not the culprit.

I thought, maybe selenium server isn't running, though I expected wdio to handle that. So I tried some stuff with `webdriver-manager`.

When I run `webdriver-manager start`, I can navigate to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub and create a session manually which fails with this message (also note the wrong system date 2018).

```
UnknownError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WINBLOWZ', ip: '192.168.0.242', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

So first try, bad experience so far. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: makre sure your driver and chrome are compatible

Comment: @PDHide you were right, had to clean out a bunch of other versions of chromedriver and now it works.

Comment: @progonkpa
Can you explain how did you do it?

Comment: @LőrinczPéter I'll formulate an answer for you but it's been a while and I don't remember exactly how I went about it.

Comment: @progonkpa No need, the problem was Chrome was not up to date with the latest version (97)

Answer (score 0):

For webdriver.io to work, it needs 3 things and I'll use Chrome as an example.

- You need chrome **browser** installed on your computer.
- You need to install chrome **webdriver**. How I understand it, this is the API that is talking to the browser.
- The versions of the installed Chrome browser and the version of chrome webdriver need to be the same.

To find out the version number of your chrome browser, go to help/about and look, in my case it was version 96.

To install the webdriver for version 96, run one of these commands.

```
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=96
npm install chromedriver --chromedriver_version=96.0.4664.110
npm install chromedriver --detect_chromedriver_version  // check your browser version, never tried this one though.
```

After this command, chrome webdriver will be added in node_modules and it should work, except if you have the same problem that I had.

I had installed the wrong version of webdriver for my browser. After I was aware of that, I installed the correct version but it still didn't work (if I remember correctly), so I needed to clean out the old chromedriver version.

I suppose you can just delete all of node_modules and npm install again, or you can remove webdrivers like so I think.

```
npm remove chromedriver --chromedriver
npm remove chromedriver --chromedriver_version=96
```

I also remember messing around with this tool in case the previous stuff didn't work out.

```
npm install webdriver-manager
webdriver-manager clean
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```